# Как в Delphi Android загрузить файл в TStream зная его Jnet_Uri?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

Пишу Android FMX приложение в Delphi 10.3 Rio. Выбираю фото в галерее (через `TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`) и получаю их пути в виде Jnet_Uri. Это отлично работает для чтения EXIF (с использованием TJExifInterface). Как мне теперь загрузить эти фото в поток (TStream) для дальнейшей работы с ними?

Когда с пробую сконвертировать Jnet_Uri в путь используя `uri.getPath`, то получаю `/document/image:26591`. `uri.toString` выдает нечто похожее - `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A26674`. `TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile` не может загрузить данные по таким путям:

> Cannot open file "/document/image:26724". No such file or directory
>   Cannot open file "/content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A26724". Not a directory

Отсюда вопрос - как, зная Jnet_Uri файла, загрузить его содержимое в TStream?

Comment: Этот же вопрос на англ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось прочитать данные через JInputStream:

```
var
  uri: Jnet_Uri;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  jis: JInputStream;
  b: TJavaArray<Byte>;
begin
  uri := .. some uri, alike "/document/image:26591"

  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;

  // Need to read via JInputStream, since Uri is not a file
  jis := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
  b := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(jis.available);
  jis.read(b);
  ms.Write(b.Data^, b.Length);
  jis.close;

   .. do something with Stream now
```